# Как сделать relation с оператором like?

Tags: php, yii2

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста, как настроить реляцию таким образом, что бы сопоставление реляции работало с оператором like, а не where, дело вот в чем:

**CategoryModel:**

```
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductModel::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getBrands()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BrandModel::className(), ['id' => 'brand_id'])->via('products');
}
```

Так мы получаем определенный список модели BrandModel, но, не совсем полный, в CategoryModel есть данные с полем path=3.10, так же как и в ProductModel список в котором значение path=3.10.13, и мне нужно выполнить реляцию так:

**CategoryModel:**

```
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductModel::className(), ['path' => 'path']);
}
```

И при этом, хочу получить не category_model.path = product_model.path, а category_model.path like product_model.path. Подскажите пожалуйста, есть решение в данном случаи? Буду очень благодарен за ваше внимание.

Запрос получается должен быть таким: SELECT * FROM TABLE category JOIN TABLE product ON product.path LIKE '%'+ category.path +'%'

Comment: _что бы сопоставление реляции работало с оператором like, а не where_ Не ровняйте тёплое с мягким. WHERE - это предложение в запросе. LIKE - это оператор.

Comment: Я понимаю, сложно было объяснить, иными словами как построить в activerecords yii2 реляцию что бы выполнить такой запрос: SELECT *
  FROM TABLE a
  JOIN TABLE b ON b.column LIKE '%'+ a.column +'%'

Comment: Думаю, Вам нужно оставить только тег _yii2_ (ну может ещё _php_) и вот это самое дополнение внести в описание задачи. А тем временем копаться в параметрах hasMany и аналогичных функций...

Comment: спасибо так и сделал.

Answer (score 1):

Такую связь сделать не получится.

[Вот код](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L620), который отвечает за добавление JOIN-а в общий запрос.